# apt being notified when a package version is available

Tags: debian, apt

For very few packages I'd like to know after an `apt-get update` if a newer version is available, is there already some option to do that?

I'm thinking about using `apt.conf` and `Post-Invoke` but done nothing yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `apt-show-versions` (in the package with the same name); running

```
apt-show-versions -u
```

will list all the packages installed on your system for which a newer version is available (using `apt`'s database, so you need to run `apt-get update` as you mention).

You can list packages as arguments to `apt-show-versions` to limit the list to those packages only; thus, running

```
apt-show-versions -u ${YOUR_WATCHED_PACKAGES}
```

after `apt-get update` will show you the information you're after. You could automate that using `Post-Invoke` as you mention.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be to run:

```
apt-get -s --only-upgrade install package1 package2 ...
```

You could put that in a script that builds the package list from a file, runs `apt-get update` and then the command above.

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up with the thing below for now, it seems to work, would have been nice if `-u` supported more packages, watching many may become slow.

`/etc/apt/watch` a text file with one package name for line (# comments supported)

`/usr/local/bin/apt-watch.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

test -f /etc/apt/watch || exit 0

apt-show-versions -u $(grep -v ^# /etc/apt/watch) >/tmp/apt.watch
if [ $(cat /tmp/apt.watch | wc -l) -gt 0 ] ; then
    cat /tmp/apt.watch | mail root -s '[apt watch] upgrades available'
fi
```

`/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99-apt-watch`:

```
# check upgrades avaiable for watched packages
APT::Update::Post-Invoke { "[ ! -x /usr/local/bin/apt-watch.sh ] || /usr/local/bin/apt-watch.sh || true"; };
```

Comment: You can specify multiple packages on `apt-show-versions`'s command line; so `apt-show-versions -u $(grep -v ^# /etc/apt/watch)` should work...

Comment: @StephenKitt thanks, it does work, thought I had checked `-u` with multiple packages, perhaps did something wrong, cool